# how to use the = operator as you create a new object?

Tags: c++, class, int, operator-overloading, operators

I have an object and I have overloaded the = operator to accept an int.

```
class jakeint
{
private:
    vector<short> theInt;
    void _setFromInt(int x);

    //operators
public:
    jakeint& jakeint::operator=(int x)
    {
        _setFromInt(x);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This works perfectly fine.  The problem is that if I want to use the = operator, I have to do this:

```
jakeint ji;
ji = 8;
```

I do want this to be doable, but I *also* would like to be able to do this:

```
jakeint ji = 8;
```

How would I go about doing this?

I realize I could just add it to the constructor and do

```
jakeint ji(8);
```

but I want these to work just like integers do.

Comment: Provide an `jakeint(int i)` alternate constructor *and* a default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor with an argument of type `int`.

```
jakeint(int x)
{
  _setFromInt(x);
}
```

With that, you could use:

```
jakeint ji = 8;
```

as well as

```
jakeint ji(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the constructor. You can specify the initialization with `=` or not, it doesn't matter. It invokes the constructor either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a constructor with argument for `jakeint ji = 8;` and `jakeint ji(8);`, such as:

```
jakeint(int x) {
    _setFromInt(x);
}
```

And if you define a constructor by yourself, you need to define a default constructor too if you still want to use `jakeint ji;`, such as:

```
jakeint() {
    _setFromInt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that takes an int, and also a copy constructor. The implicit copy constructor is fine in this case. (The actual call to the copy ctor is usually elided.)

Answer (score 0):

`jakeint ji = 8;` is just a shorthand alias for `jakeint ji(8);`, they are identical, so you do need to add a constructor that takes an `int` as input, as other people have showed you.